# Dealing with dynamic ids. How do I click on exactly the 3rd highlight of this xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, sapui5

I have a SAPUI page which I am navigating using Selenium WebDriver for an automation testing framework.

There's a point in the flow where I encountered click which actually has 3 similar xpaths.

The problem is that the id is dynamic and so is everything else in it except maybe the aria-posinset and the text. I could never get it to be clicked by using id. Also, I am still not able to click on it using the below xpath. It just says element is not clickable. When I use Chrome Developer Tool to look up the xpath using :hover, the 3rd highlight below is the one which actually hovers upon the click. So, I'd like to use the 3rd highlight of this xpath. Can you guys please help me out here?

This is the xpath in question:

```
//a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')]
```

These are the 3 highlights from the Chrome Developer Tool with the same xpath.

1:

```
<a id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_2293" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_2293" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="3" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Quotes</a>
```

2.

```
<a id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_3033" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_3033" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="3" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Quotes</a>
```

3.

```
<a id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_3773" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_3773" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="3" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Quotes</a>
```

How do I click on the 3rd xpath here? I actually want to click on "Quotes" which will continue the flow ahead.

Just in case I am not clear, I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java and the browser is Firefox.

**UPDATE:**

I tried using Actions class but even that failed but with a different error this time:

```
//div[@role='Main']/div[2]/div[@role='Navigation']/nav/ul/li/a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')]
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Element <a id="navigationitemu3p1aB5MBqswlRFv6wRSym_91" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" href="#"> is not clickable at point (902.2166519165039,67.25833129882812) because another element <div id="sapClientBusyIndicatorMobileContainer" class="sapClientBusyIndicatorMobileContainer"> obscures it
```

Comment: If I am not wrong your first & second `<a>` tags are identical which is not as per the expectation. Can you have a relook please?

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Or is it finding the wrong element? This xpath works for me `xpath=//a[text()='Quotes'][3]`.

Comment: It is unable to click on the element defined by the xpath. I have not used the [3] like you said. So per the syntax, should I just add a [3] at the end? Because when I use [3] in my xpath, as in the original post, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming this is part of some larger table, etc. You will likely have to click the Quotes link based on the contained text of some other element, e.g. these are Quotes links for Thing A, Thing B, and Thing C and you want to click the Quotes link next to Thing C. Post some of the surrounding HTML for the 3rd link and tell us what it is about the 3rd link that makes you want to click on it, i.e. it's next to the text Thing C or whatever.

Comment: @JeffC Your comment seems to me redundant after the answer was posted. Can you explain how your `some of the surrounding HTML` is different from `parent_tag` mentioned in the answer? I even don't see a reason for you to downvote the question even.

Comment: My comment is addressing locating the desired element by relative contained text. Your answer does not address that. You are just choosing the third element which is likely going to be brittle if the contents of the page change. Your answer is also so generic as to not even be useful. That's why I'm asking for more info in a comment rather than posting an answer that doesn't add anything or answer the question.

Comment: @JeffC Incase you feel _answer does not address that_ try to answer to questions, thats what _Stackoverflow.com_ is all about rather mis-interpreting other solutions. Again _addressing locating the desired element_ must not be through a comment but through an Answer. Perhaps you need to revisit  [**Difference between addressing and answering a question**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108672/difference-between-addressing-and-answering-a-question) for a clear understanding.

Comment: I understand just fine. Did you read my comment? It doesn't attempt to answer the question, it asks the OP for more info... `Post some of the surrounding HTML for the 3rd link and tell us what it is about the 3rd link that makes you want to click on it`... info that is needed to properly answer the question. You have this bad habit of misunderstanding the question, my comment, etc. and then blaming your misunderstanding on me and others.

Comment: @JeffC Can you please take some time to answer my basic and priliminary question about how your `some of the surrounding HTML` is different from `parent_tag` mentioned in the answer?`

Comment: @DebanjanB All you are adding in your answer is an index. You can do that as `//a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')][3]` and it will accomplish what you intended. I tested it. I don't think that's the best approach, as I've said before. I think OP is wanting the 3rd instance because of some text that is contained in the ancestor HTML that has not been posted. I want OP to post that HTML so a better, more dynamic answer can be provided.

Comment: @JeffC Please go through the _xpath_ Specs. `/following-sibling::a[3]` is a valid _xpath expression_ and I didn't find a reference so far that it isn't _the best approach_. While you wait for several questions to be updated by several OP you are down-voting penitential good answers.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared it will be tough to construct a proper answer as all the 3 elements have similar attributes sans the last part of `id` and `data-sap-ui` attribute.

If the intended link always shows up as the **3rd** element you can identify the parent node first and adopt the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//parent_tag//following-sibling::a[3]")).click();
```

**Note** : Replace the `parent_tag` with the proper `tagName[attribute='value']`

Comment: OP has already posted the XPath that returns the three elements. What does this answer add to that? He's already stated that adding `[3]` to the XPath doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffC I am afraid may be you have failed again to understand what OP have tried and how my solution tries to guide him to solve the question. I am sure you still don't know how OP have used `[3]` either with `findElement()` or `findElements()`. Please take utmost care to understand what OP requires and how a solution addresses a question else you wouldn't improvise.

Comment: OP already has a locator that finds the three elements. Changing that locator to some other method of finding the exact same three elements doesn't help anything. I'm not sure why you think that contributes anything.

Comment: I am afraid. Possibly you have misread OP's question and need to reread again. OP mentioned about the locator  with _xpath_ as `//a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')]` which through _Chrome Developer Tool_ identifies 3 similar _child nodes_. Perhaps you need to look at the _xpath_ documentation then you will understand that the _xpath_ within my answer i.e. `"//parent_tag//following-sibling::a[3]"` would identify only **one single** element only.

Comment: Your locator won't identify anything because it's full of placeholder information. My point was that the OP has already posted a locator that locates the three elements, one of which is the correct element. If you want to post a locator that selects the single correct element, perhaps you should start with one that works and then add an index to it, etc. to have it locate the element OP wants. I don't think that's the best approach because it's not dynamic. That's why I was asking for additional information before I attempted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this and it will click on the 3rd element found on the webpage.

**Xpath :**    `(//a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')])[3]`

**Complete code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')])[3]")).click();
```

***If above code don't work try below code:***

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@aria-posinset='3' and contains(text(),'Quotes')])[3]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. This was one of the first xpaths I tried. It gives a org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException. Neither does the JavascriptExecutor working. I have tried these without success.